# Call JavaScript functions from .NET methods in ASP.NET Core Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

JavaScript function that I want to call from my ASP.NET Core Blazor app:

```
export function onClick(map) {
    var latLng = null;
    function onMapClick(e) {
        latLng = map.unproject(e.point).toString();
        alert("You clicked the map at " + latLng); // Here is "You clicked the map at + actual value of latLng"
    }
    map.on('click', onMapClick);
    alert("You clicked the map at 123 " + latLng); // And then "You clicked the map at + null" instead of latLng variable
    return String(yourGlobalVariable);
}
```

C# code where I'm calling that function:

```
        string res = await mapModule.InvokeAsync<string>("onClick", mapInstance);
```

Where mapInstance and mapModule are IJSObjectReference

The question is: Why in the first alert I'm getting an actual value that I've assigned to latLng variable in the function onMapClick and then I get null outside the function although the variable is global?

I've tried similar code here: http://jsfiddle.net/mufjkv6r/1/ and it works

Comment: How did you set up the js module?  I know it should be  possible now in Blazor but it doesn't look trivial.

Comment: @HenkHolteman, 
mapModule = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>( "import", "./mapComponent.js"); - as trivial as that
It is from example: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: Why in the first alert I'm getting an actual value
> that I've assigned to latLng variable in the function onMapClick and
> then I get null outside the function although the variable is global?

First thing I want to say is Jsfiddle contain normal flow of execution, which is executing one line after another.

> ```
>  var latLng = null;
>     function onMapClick(e) {
>         latLng = map.unproject(e.point).toString();
>         alert("You clicked the map at " + latLng); // Here is "You clicked the map at + actual value of latLng"
>     }
>     map.on('click', onMapClick);
>     alert("You clicked the map at 123 " + latLng); // And then "You clicked the map at + null" instead of latLng variable
>     return String(yourGlobalVariable);
> ```

but the above code will not call `onMapClick` function unless you clicked on the map. So the `latLng` will be `null` at that point of time.

Comment: Exactly, so the problem starts after clicking the map, I've got two alerts, first one with value, second one with null

Comment: if you really need second alert then you can try it inside timer (not recommended) . `var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
        if (latLng) {
            alert("you clicked the map at " + latLng);
            clearInterval(checkExist);
        }
    }, 100);`

Comment: I don’t, I need this function to return a value not null

Comment: I think better solution would be calling `c#` method from your `onMapClick` js function instead of returning ` latLng` from js.  Since, `latLng` is setting asynchronously.

Comment: why is it better? I took example from Microsoft docs and mapModule is returning an object without problem

Comment: but in your case `latLng` is setting asynchronously. in that scenario, we have two options. one is wait for the `latLng` to set (not recommended) or call c# method from js

Comment: this is not the problem, to show it I used alerts, inside inner function variable has value but outside it seems to reassign somehow

Comment: ` map.on('click', onMapClick);` this is just registering for on click event(not calling `onMapClick` function). and you are using `latLng` immediately after this. so at that time` onMapClick` function is not called(so `latLng` will be null).

Comment: why? map.on is calling that function and In the first alert I can see the correct value